# Как изменить текст, который не влазит на "..." Qt

Tags: qt, pyqt5

Есть QLabel. Я в него заношу текст. Когда текст большой, то он не влазит и выходит за границы. Как сделать так, чтобы та часть текста, которая не влазит заменялась на "..." 
[image: вот так]

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимальный пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: На фотографии видно, как текст залазит (внизу) на дату(слева) и время(справа)

Comment: Видно так видно.

Comment: может высоту лейбла чуть уменьшить с конца, чтоб он не был под датой и временем